# How to control firefox multi-account containers using python and selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, firefox-addon, ui-automation

I am working on a web automation project, which involves working with the same webpage but different accounts at the same time. For this purpose, I am using firefox multi-account containers.

Can anyone help me with how to automate container operations using python and selenium, eg, open a site in a new tab with specific container?

Comment: Do you have a profile for each container? If so you can do something like the following to specify which container to run: 

`from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('path/to/your/profile')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)`

Comment: unfortunately no, and I have so many containers now